# how to convert binary field to image file in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to load blob field in Power Bi.Field is getting converted to Binary in Power Bi. [image]
How to convert this Binary to Image file in Power Query using Power BI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to Load Images in Power Bi

1. After we connect to the SQL Server and load the table, go to Power Query Editor.
2. Change the data type of `Manifest`/Column which contain image/binary data, from `Binary` to `Text`.
   We need to add one more column to convert `Text` to `Image URL` format.
3. Go to "Add Column" and click on "Custom Column". It will open a window. Enter the column name and formula given below and click OK.

   “data:image/;base64,”&[ImageData]
4. Now click on "Close and Apply" from the Home tab.
5. On Data tab, select Image column and change its `Data Category` to `Image URL`.
6. To use the image in the report, go to the Report tab. Add `Table` visual and select Image column or we can have custom visuals to show the image from the marketplace also.

**Note**
The better way would be to store the image in a server and load the URL from your dataset. This will reduce the size of your dataset.